# Transatlantic cruises allowing casual dressing?

Tags: europe, clothing, cruising, north-america, dress-codes

I am looking at transatlantic cruises as an alternative to planes and while searching and reading about the topic, I am wondering about dress code. It appears that many cruise companies offer luxury or semi-luxury cruises which involves people to dress up some evenings or even all evenings.

I am not really into that and I was searching for cruises letting me go around with jeans all the time. I am wondering how to restrict my searches to this kind of cruises. I for example found that [Costa offers some transatlantic cruise](http://www.cruises.com/sc.do?c=14&v=683&i=888984&d=10/31/2014&d2=04/29/2017&dsc=y&tab=foodanddining) that involves dressing up some nights in the main restaurant but you can escape and go to a buffet restaurant at no extra cost.

So I am targeting these cruises that let me go around with casual clothes like jeans at any time, even if I have to avoid some parts of the boat some nights. Is there a search engine or a way to find these (by sticking to some specific company for example)? I am mostly interested in transatlantic cruises (i.e. North America to Europe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's going to vary so much from ship to ship - back in the day it was easier, but these days there's such variety.

[CruiseCritic](http://www.cruisecritic.com/articles.cfm?ID=545) has a list of dress-codes by cruise line for about a dozen cruises, that's probably about the best list or method you're going to get. Alternatively you can google each cruise ship and add the search term 'dress code' but that would take a while (but you did ask for a way ;)).